# Display direct child if its class name matches parents class name with fixed list of names

Tags: css, less

I am learning less and there's one thing that was always tedious in raw CSS. Often, there will be a div for indicating more states of the application, like that:

```
<div class="result">
    <div class="success">Request processed OK.</div>
    <div class="error">There was an error processing request.</div>
    <div class="working">Sending your inquiry...</div>
</div>
```

Now how I typically design this is to assign class name to the `.result` div that reflects the current state. The motivation here is to avoid setting CSS styles directly to the elements.

```
/** hide all child nodes by default**/
div.result>div {
    display: none;
}
/** when error state occurs, show the error div **/
div.result.error>div.error {
    display: block;
}
```

This solution is more robust as it allows other changes to be also done by single CSS class change. For example you can imagine instead setting the `.error` on the entire form or even the entire application and it having multiple effects.

So now the question is, is it possible to use LESS to generate the `div.result.error>div.error` sequence for each class name? I imagine something like:

```
.result {
        & > div {
            display: none;
        }

        LESS_FOR_EACH(error, success, working) &.$ENTRY > div.$ENTRY {
            display: block;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about CSS variables to handle this:

```css
.error {
  display:var(--error,none)!important;
}

.success {
  display:var(--success,none)!important;
}

.working {
  display:var(--working,none)!important;
}
```

```html
<div class="result" style="--error:block">
    <div class="success">Request processed OK.</div>
    <div class="error">There was an error processing request.</div>
    <div class="working">Sending your inquiry...</div>
</div>

<div class="result" style="--working:block">
    <div class="success">Request processed OK.</div>
    <div class="error">There was an error processing request.</div>
    <div class="working">Sending your inquiry...</div>
</div>
```

You can easily generate the code using SASS:

```
$classes: "error", "working","success";

@each $m in $classes {
  .#{$m} {
     display:var(--#{$m},none)!important;
  }
}
```

And LESS

```
@classes: error, working, success;

each(@classes, {
  .@{value} {
     display: e(%("var(--%a,none)!important", @value));
  }
});
```

---

To directly answer your question you can do the following

```
@classes: error, working, success;

.result {
   & > div {
       display: none;
   }
        
   each(@classes, {
     &.@{value} > div.@{value} {
        display: block;
     }
    });
}
```

Comment: Awesome answer. I have actually found a solution 10 mins ago, but your solution is much less ugly.